# Ubuntu stuck at installing grub2 package after "fix"

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Im doing dual boot with windows. I installed windows 10 first. The installer keeps getting stuck at the installation of grub2 package.

I tried the suggestion mentioned in the thread "Ubuntu install hangs at “Installing the 'grub2' package…”", but the problem still persists.

I'm installing Ubuntu 16.04.3 desktop amd64.

Comment: are you installing EFI?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with EFI. I do have windows 10 already installed on the C partition, and I'm trying to install Ubuntu on the D partition. I'm sorry for being slightly on the noobish side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) If you aren't familiar with UEFI then you must be before even consider installing an OS.

Comment: OK I looked it up, and I definitely have UEFI. How can I fix my problem now?

Comment: And I just tried it with Ubuntu 17, and the same happens. I'm frustrated. It's always stuck at "source ID was not found when attempting to remove it, Glib.self_remove(self.timeout_id)"